# help me being the next zuckerberg

Tags: web-development

I really expect someone to help me with my problem as stated below.

I started learning website making by having tutorials from w3schools.com but after doing taking the HTML tutorials I don't think I really can do anything with it. Maybe I don't know everything about HTML yet. I know the online tutorials are not enough but what I need you guys to tell me is that how can I learn making some nice websites. I have vacations for two months now and I think it would be the best time for me to learn making websites as I really love to be a website developer. Now I would like to start from the scratch. I know some C language *(though I know it will not help me)*. So tell me from where shall I learn HTML and what all things shall I learn after that and in what order. If you can also help me with the material *(let it be books or online tutorials)*. But I would like to know how can I gain confidence that I can make some websites as just learning online tutorials doesn't help me much. I also tried some video tutorials but in that too, they will just tell me some of the functions and not all. So what am I supposed to do.. just know a limited functions as they want me to know in video tutorials or do something else.

Comment: bad heading.. + w3schools is not trustful, even a [website](http://w3fools.com) has been made to criticize w3school.com. You should look at [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

HTML is the way to display the information that you want to display, if you want to be the next Mark Zuckerberg, HTML has very little to do to it... Facebook in general is a programming masterpiece with countless hours put into it.

But to answer your question, you'll need a mix of several technologies in order to be a prolific web developer:

1. Database server /  Database display - pick any of the SQL database server you'd like, and start learning how to create efficient queries.
2. Server Side Scripting - that comes in the form of either Java *(and using the powerful servlets)*, PHP or .net.
3. Client Side Scripting - JavaScript comes in handly in scripting of client side scripting, as well as to create AJAX components (meaning - updating a certain part of the page, instead of refreshing it whole, like the activity feed on Facebook).
4. Client Side Parsing - for that you'll need to know HTML as well as CSS.

Good luck!

Comment: dont take me wrong.. but how much do you think it willtake to learn it all!:P

Comment: @karan, you can pick up the conceptual basics in a few days, but developing a true, instinctual understanding of all four bullet points in this answer will take *years*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to know what you want to do before you can find out what you need to get there. Once you've got the idea then you can ask questions here, or on stackoverflow.com on how to achieve that. Or if someone's doing something like you want on an existing website, then ask how they did it.